# What can one expect from Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using vs2008 sp1. I've just downloaded VWD2010 Express. I don't know if I placed to much expectations on it, but there are at least 3 things that made me sad:

1. On the logo it said: "use this product for evaluation only." I've never seen something like that on VWD2008 Express.
2. There's no possibility of creating an **empty solution**. I checked online to this if I could download such a template, but I didn't get any.
3. using **<%: %>** is not working. I still need to use **<% = %>** to make it work.

   I wonder what we can expect from that product. May be I didn't download the right product.

Is there anything I can do? or I might keep using VS2008 professional.

**EDIT**

if <% : %> is related to .NET4 and VWD 2010 Express uses .NET 4 by default, why I can't use it without getting errors?

Thanks for helping

Comment: what's <%: %> for? I've not used it before...

Comment: Well, it replaces both <% = %> and <% = Html.Encode()%>. For instance, instead of writing <% = Html.Encode(Model.MyProperty)%> or <% = Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyProperty)%>, you can write <%: Model.Property%> or <%:TextBoxFor(x => x.MyProperty)%>

Comment: ah that's rather handy, thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you register the "use this product for evaluation only" will be gone

Comment: Thanks for the registration. However, how about the empty solution? and the use of colon? <% : %>

Comment: Be sure to ask questions the Smart Way.  One question per thread.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks for your thought.